# Is there any way to send mails regulary using Sendgrid?

Tags: django, sendgrid

I want to send monthly notifications to users that log on to my website. I've thought of using Sendgrid's Marketing campaigns to send monthly mails but it doesn't fit perfectly to my needs. I'll have to keep adding emails to the automation at a month's duration and that doesn't seem the right way to do it.

Comment: a simple script running on a cron job can do the trick.

Comment: I don't know what a cron job is but I'll check it out.
Thanks

Comment: cron is basically a scheduler that comes with Linux by default. You can run scripts periodically with it. Hope [this](https://www.netiq.com/documentation/cloud-manager-2-5/ncm-reference/data/bexyssf.html) helps.

Comment: I tried to use cron as given in this [link](https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-django/) but I am getting a module error for 'fcntl' when I run the command "python manage.py crontab add". On further search, I learned that this module is for Linux OS and I am using Windows. Is there any way I can solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Celery.

```
from celery.schedules import crontab


def setup_periodic_tasks(app):
    app.conf.beat_schedule = {
        'monthly-email': {
            'task': '[APP NAME].tasks.[FUNCTION NAME]',
            'schedule':
        },
```

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules